# What do the letters in `fc` command stand for?

Tags: zsh, command, posix

I just came across the [`fc`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uhistory.htm) command which lets you edit the previous command and issue it afterwards.

It has its own `FCEDIT` environment variable for setting its editor, and a man page in *POSIX Programmer's Manual* (`1p`).

It creates a file in `/tmp` directory and executes the contents if the file is saved (`:wq` in `vim`).

Apart from that, it can number and list `fc -l` previously executed commands to choose from.

So it's really nice and handy command to know.

The question is what does its name really mean; how to associate the command with its function in mind?

"First-class"? or maybe even just as "Function" (what came to my mind after composing the previous sentence)?

The manual refers to it simply as "the fc utility".

Comment: Thanks for asking this; I have wondered for a long time what the mechanism that pressing ^X,^E used to perform that function.

Comment: See also [Export Command History into a Shell Script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181459/86440).

Comment: Theres a lot of cool history expansions you can do as well... `!!` is the previous command, `!-2` is the command before that, `!-3` to `!-N` etc. Then `!:1` gives you the first argument from the previous command, `!:2`, the second argument, `!*` all the arguments, `^command1^command2` execute last command1 replacing instance of command1 with command2, etc.

Comment: there's also a similar [third-pary command](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) with predictive improvements.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although the `zshbuiltins(1)` man page does not indicate it, the `fc` command is pretty much the same as its `bash` counterpart. Simply (F)ix (C)ommand.

Comment: Thank. It makes sense and sounds perfect. I switched to `bash` issuing `help fc` (`help` being a utility for shell built-ins) but the output doesn't note that too, and neither `whatis fc`.

Comment: You could try `man bash` or `man builtins`. Or view https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash.

Comment: `fc` is a POSIX command,which originated in ksh AFAIK (already there in ksh86, already called _fix command_ back then). zsh has had it since the first release in 1990.  I don't know about bash. bash 1.05 didn't have it.

Comment: Great! I had to confirm that :P